# How do I generate an internally-celled border between Cards in Semantic-UI

Tags: css, reactjs, semantic-ui

I'm using the [Card](http://react.semantic-ui.com/views/card) component from Semantic-UI. I won't know in advance how many cards will be rendered. I'd like to put a border between inward facing sides of the card, similar to the way its done in [Grid](http://react.semantic-ui.com/collections/grid#internally-celled). What's an elegant way to do this?

Here's my bit of code:

```
renderCategoryCards(){
  return this.props.grid.map((grid_cat) => {
    return ( <CategoryCard key={grid_cat._id} category={grid_cat}/> )
  })
}

render() {
  return (
    <div className="categories-wrapper">
      <Card.Group itemsPerRow={3} stackable>
          {this.renderCategoryCards()}
      </Card.Group>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Solved this. `render() {
    return (
      <Grid className="categories-wrapper" celled='internally' container stackable centered columns='equal'>
        {this.generateRows()}
      </Grid>
    );
  }
}`

Answer (score 0):

```
render() { return ( <Grid className="categories-wrapper" celled='internally' container stackable centered columns='equal'> {this.generateRows()} </Grid> ); } }
```